# How to comprehend the formula of life expectancy?

Tags: statistics, actuarial-science

I want to know how to comprehend the $e_x$. In my view, $T_x$ is the total number of people lived at and over age $x$. Dividing $T_x$ by $l_x$ represents the concept of "times".
Why dividing $T_x$ by $l_x$ is life expectancy? I am still confused about the concept of "person-years".

$l_x$: number of survivors at exact age x in the life table population
$L_x$: the average life table population at risk of dying between ages $x$ and $x+1$
$L_x=\frac{1}{2}(l_x+l_{x+1})$
$T_x=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}L_{x+t}$: person-years lived at and over age $x$
$e_x=\frac{T_x}{l_x}$: life expectancy at age $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e_x$ is the mean number of years a person will live once s/he has already lived to age $x$.  Person-years is the integral of the number of people still alive with respect to time.  For an example, let us assume everybody lives whole years, so they die exactly at some new year's.  If we start the year with $10$ people, $5$ of whom will die in one year, $3$ of whom will die in three years, $1$ will die in $5$ years, and $1$ will die in $11$ years, they have $5 \cdot 1 + 3\cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 5 + 1 \cdot 11=30$ person-years of life remaining among them.  Dividing by the $10$ people, they each have an expected life of $3$ years remaining.